# Match values from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, match

Given 2 tables, TableA and TableB, how can I get the "id"s of TableA when the "value" doesn't match with any "value" of TableB?

**Table A**

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
| 1  |   a   |
| 2  |   b   |
| 3  |   c   |
| 4  |   d   |
| 5  |   e   |
+----+-------+
```

**Table B**

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
| 1  |   a   |
| 2  |   b   |
| 3  |   c   |
| 4  |   c   |
| 5  |   f   |
+----+-------+
```

**Result Table**

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 4  |
| 5  |
+----+
```

**EDITED (SQLFiddle):** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c8c9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to validate that the id/value are the same in both tables then use:

```
select distinct id
from tablea
where (id, value) not in (select id, value
                          from tableb)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a881/4)

If you want to compare only the values:

```
select distinct id
from tablea
where (value) not in (select value
                          from tableb)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2230/2)

Comment: Both answers have a problem! If table B has the values but not in the same order, then it doesn't work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2230/1

Comment: @kairos that is because the original query was checking both id and value, if you remove id it should work -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2230/2

Comment: @kairos based on the sample it would still be 4,5 because d,e in tableA do not exist in tableB

Comment: I removed my comment when i saw it was stupid. Sorry!! your answer is, of course, correct!

Answer (score 3):

```
select a.id
from tableA a
left outer join tableB b on a.id = b.id and a.value = b.value
where a.id is not null and b.value is null
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3db18/2)

Comment: 6ms in Fiddle, whatever it means... @bluefeet suggestion toke 1ms.. I give a + to both but I'll adopt his answer (based on this pseudo-benchmark)

Comment: You did insert into tableA twice in your fiddle.